# Saving vs. submitting a form

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on an application process using Laravel 4.2.

Users applying with my form need to be able to save their form input for later, or submit it. So right now I have two different buttons, Save and Submit.

The key difference between saving and submitting would be a status. When a user saves their application, their application status will be marked as "in progress", when they submit their application the status would be marked as "completed".

**My question is:**

In terms of my form HTML structure, How do I differentiate between a saved and submitted application? Just checking whether or not they have filled out all the required inputs would not be reliable, because there is the possibility that the user wanted to add more to it later.

I tried doing a form inside of a form, but quickly realized this would not work.

Does anyone have an idea as to how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two submit buttons inside a form with different names and values:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="save">Save</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="submit">Submit</button>
```

You can then check the value in your controller action:

```
public function postSubmission()
{
    if (Request::get('action') == 'save')
    {
        // Save form for later
    }
    elseif (Request::get('action') == 'submit')
    {
        // Immediately submit form
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your code is something like this (this is from Laravel5 but as far as i remember it's mostly the same).

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('admin.editApplication'), 'method' => 'PATCH')) !!}
    ....
    <button type="submit" name="save" value="save">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" name="edit" value="edit">Edit</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Then in your controller you can do something like this (check if the value is set in edit (you might want to call it something else than edit and save)

```
public function editApplication(Request $request) {
    if(isset($request->input('save')){
        // Your code to save here
    }else{
       // Your code to edit here.
    }
}
```